# Running "npm link" broke yarn and npm?

Tags: npm, npm-link

I ran `npm link` in a project. I got some error message and ran `npm unlink` to get back to where I were.

Now many essential npm and yarn commands have stopped working.

For example:

```
PS C:\Users\SESA572442\Dev\graphics\tgml> yarn build
yarn run v1.22.0
$ rimraf dist .rpt2_cache
'rimraf' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
error Command failed with exit code 1.
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.
```

How can I clean up the mess from npm link?

Answer (score 0):

Removing `node_modules` resolved the problem.